# References or Sources - What should be used where and why?

Tags: word-choice

These days, I'm writing on herbs and their effects on human health. At times, I find various journals' quotes and scientific researches mentioned as **Sources** and other times **References**.

Whilst both seem okay to me, is there any subtle yet interesting difference?

Comment: Recommended readings: [Citations and References: Documenting your Sources](http://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/res/res-citsandrefs.html), [Academic writing: Citing sources](http://www.uefap.com/writing/citation/citefram.htm), [Wikipedia: Citing sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_sources).

Answer (score 1):

When research talks about sources, it means another load of information it's stealing from. I've always known a reference being something that **links to** a source.

For example, the London Eye is, for all intents and purposes, a *source*. All the signs around the area that point towards the London Eye (as if such an impressive spectacle really needs to be signposted) *reference the source*.

References are normally kept in a bibliography at the end of a piece of work, and these *link to* or *name and give credit to* the source, where the source is *the actual information*.

Comment: *When research talks about sources* - from this very first line, you din' get me! I'm pretty clear **if research talks** about the sources. I talked about some article on herb's benefit on cardiovascular disease. Down there, at times, you see *references* and other times *sources.*